# How to get column by number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What I'd like to do is

```
=AVERAGE(col(2)2:col(2):5, col(5)2:col(5):5,, col(9)2:col(9):5)
```

As you can see, instead of using `B2` to reference a cell, I've swapped the `B` for a fictional `col(2)` where the number 2 = B

Is this possible?

Context if helpful:

I have some data that looks like this (this is the result of a survey)

```
        A        B        C        D
1       ID        Q1       Q2       Q3
2       1         3        1        2
3       2         4        5        4
```

In this case, Q = question and the number is the score given to the question.

I want to calculate the average based upon specific columns. In this case, I only want to total all of column B and column D.

I know how to do that using `average`, but the bit I'm stuck on is how do I grab the column by a number! As you can see, B is question 1, C is question 2, D is question 3 (and this goes up to AZ).

I did think about adding an extra row to represent the question

```
        A        B        C        D
1                1        2        3 
2      ID        Q1       Q2       Q3
3      1         3        1        2
4      2         4        5        4
```

And then maybe use `match` but I got so lost, it's not worth sharing what I tried here

Comment: You mean to say that you need AVERAGE of  B in Row 5 also Col D Average in Row 5 Or,,,Average of B3,D3 in E3 and so next ,,, I mean to say Average in ROW or in COLUMN ?

Answer (score 2):

To average certain columns by number, you can use the `INDEX` with an array argument for the `columns`.

eg. in your example:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX($A2:$D2,1,{2,4}))
```

would average columns 2 and 4

If the column numbers are random, you'll need to hard-code them as I show into an array constant; if there is a mathematical relationship, a formula may be more convenient to generate the array of column numbers.

Since `INDEX` is returning only the relevant columns, you can use any function that takes an array for an argument.

***Earlier** versions of Excel may require a different formula, so post back if this approach does not work for you, and exactly what it does not do (or error message).*

[image]